# Moving message ticker in SLDS

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

Is there a way to add a moving ticker in the lightning page ?

In the classic mode I had added the marquee in the apex page like this

```
      <marquee>   
           <b style="color: rgb(204, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, 
              sans-serif; font-size: medium;">
            Cannot access Salesforce. Maintenance occurring at the moment. 
           </b> 
      </marquee>
```

How can I do something similar in Lightning ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The HTML `marquee` tag is deprecated and its use is not recommended (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee). The reason for this is that moving text is very hard to read. I would suggest instead applying some attention-grabbing notification styling to it. The Lightning Design System has some great choices for you: https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/notifications/#flavor-alert-error.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Just designed a working model in Lightning.Hope it helps. 
So as to view the component demon create an Application:

```
<c:SetInterbval Demo/>

    <aura:application >
        <c:SetInterval />
    </aura:application>

<c:SetInterval />
```

Component

```
<aura:component >
     <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
     <aura:attribute name="intervalId" type="Integer" default="0"/>
         <aura:attribute name="intervalId2" type="Integer" default="0"/>
    <div  id="div1" >
        <p style="position: relative;height:100px;width:100px;color:white;" 
           id="tofloat">I am Floating Left to Right</p>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
       var lWidth = window.screen.width ;//get device size.
       // alert(lWidth);
       window.setInterval($A.getCallback(function() { 
                helper.shiftDiv(component, event, helper,lWidth);
            } ), 100);
    },          
})
```

Helper

```
({
     shiftDiv: function(component, event, helper,lWidth) {
            var changeposition=component.get("v.intervalId");
            var myimage = document.getElementById('tofloat');     
            if(changeposition <lWidth){
            //  console.log("ok"+changeposition);
              myimage.style.left=changeposition+'px';
              myimage.style.background="radial-gradient(green,blue)";
              changeposition=changeposition+5;
              component.set("v.intervalId",changeposition);
         }
              //reset the left to 0
         else{
                   component.set("v.intervalId",0);
                   myimage.style.left="0px";
                  changeposition=component.get("v.intervalId");//resetting so as to hit the if block again
         }

     }
})
```

Style

```
.THIS#div1{

       border: 5px solid;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: beige;
    width: 1366px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Comment: <aura:application >
    <c:SetInterval />
</aura:application>

<c:SetInterval />
Cmp-----
<aura:component >
     <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
     <aura:attribute name="intervalId" type="Integer" default="0"/>
         <aura:attribute name="intervalId2" type="Integer" default="0"/>
 <div  id="div1" >
        <p style="position: relative;height:100px;width:100px;color:white;" 
           id="tofloat">I am Floating Left to Right</p>
    </div>
</aura:component>

Comment: missed part of code